# How can I keep aspect ratio of background-image in css

Tags: html, css, image

I'm currently working of the mobile version of a website and I want all images to fill 90% of the screen width. I think the best technique to achieve this is creating a div for every image which is using the image as background-image. The problem is that I don't know how to match the height of the div with the aspect ratio of the image. I have tried to set width: 90% and height: auto but it didn't worked.

Could you please help me?
Lennart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I might be getting the question wrong, but I don't understand why you want to use background images?

If you use a regular img-Tag, the image will keep its aspect ratio if you set it to 
width: 90%
height: auto

Other than that you can keep the aspect ratio of a div-container by setting a padding-top to a percentage on a wrapper-div. That works because the percentage is calculated dependend on the width of the div. See more here: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: Thank you! :) I didn't know it was possible to set the height of an img object to auto. That did it.

Answer (score 4):

You have an option in CSS called [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) with the option `cover`:

```
background-size: cover;
```

> A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom. The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

Comment: Thanks, but I have two problems using this keyword: Firstly, if the resolution of the screen (or browser window) is less than the image, the image is not resizing, instead it is just being cropped. Secondly, I will still have to set a fixed height for the image. Depending on the images height, there will be a padding between it and the objects below.